# Sequelize : less-than operator return only one row, In raw query return all row

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, nodes

when using less-than or less-than-equal then I only get one row. but I want to filter by date.

> **associations:**

```
db.orders.hasMany(db.sales, { foreignKey: "orderId", as: "sale", });
db.sales.belongsTo(db.orders, { foreignKey: "orderId", as: "order", });
db.sales.belongsTo(db.auths, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "user", });
db.sales.belongsTo(db.dues, { foreignKey: "dueId", as: "due", });
db.sales.belongsTo(db.customers, { foreignKey: "customerId", as: "customer", });
db.sales.belongsTo(db.returns, { foreignKey: "returnId", as: "return", });
```

> only raw query -
> **Sequelize Raw Query code:**

```
let date = req.params.date;
const currentTime = new Date().toISOString();
const today = moment(currentTime).tz("Asia/Dhaka").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const last = moment(today)
  .subtract(date, "d")
  .tz("Asia/Dhaka")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD");

let order = await db.sequelize.query(
  "SELECT * FROM `orders`  WHERE date <= :last",
  {
    replacements: { last: last },
    type: db.sequelize.SELECT,
    nest: true,
    all: true,
  }
);
```

**Sequelize Raw Query output:**

```
"success": 1,
"order": [
    {
        "id": 264,
        "orderId": "YFEP6EP41",
        "date": "2022-12-29",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 265,
        "orderId": "PVDZGSQIO",
        "date": "2022-12-29",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:43:27.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 267,
        "orderId": "-7LDATFVL",
        "date": "2023-01-02",
        "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z"
    }
]
```

> only less-than-equal
> **Using sequlize Less-than operator code:**

```
 let date = req.params.date;
const currentTime = new Date().toISOString();
const today = moment(currentTime).tz("Asia/Dhaka").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const last = moment(today)
  .subtract(date, "d")
  .tz("Asia/Dhaka")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD");

let order = await Order.findAll({
  include: {
    all: true,
    nested: true,
    attributes: {
      exclude: ["id", "email", "password", "roleId"],
    },
  },
  where: {
    date: {
      [db.lte]: last,
    },
  },
});
```

**Using sequlize Less-than operator output:**

```
"success": 1,
"order": [
    {
        "id": 267,
        "orderId": "-7LDATFVL",
        "date": "2023-01-02",
        "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
        "sale": [
            {
                "name": "Keyboard",
                "quantity": 1,
                "date": "2023-01-02",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
                "status": "due",
                "percentage": "0.00",
                "less": "0.00",
                "discountPrice": "20050.90",
                "deposit": "0.00",
                "change": "0.00",
                "subtotal": "20050.90",
                "userId": 1,
                "orderId": 267,
                "customerId": 126,
                "dueId": 92,
                "returnId": null,
                "user": {
                    "name": "Leaon H.",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Admin"
                    }
                },
                "due": {
                    "title": "Purchased Product",
                    "description": null,
                    "date": "2023-01-02",
                    "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
                    "amount": "20050.90",
                    "remain": "20050.90",
                    "fullPaidDate": null,
                    "collection": "0.00",
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "paid": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    }
                },
                "customer": {
                    "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                    "phone": "123",
                    "address": "1"
                },
                "return": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

> But I want this type of **output**:

```
"success": 1,
"orders": [
    {
        "id": 264,
        "orderId": "YFEP6EP41",
        "date": "2022-12-29",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
        "sale": [
            {
                "name": "Keyboard",
                "quantity": 3,
                "date": "2022-12-29",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                "status": "due",
                "percentage": "20.00",
                "less": "66128.58",
                "discountPrice": "264000.00",
                "deposit": "264510.00",
                "change": "0.00",
                "subtotal": "330000.00",
                "userId": 1,
                "orderId": 264,
                "customerId": 126,
                "dueId": 90,
                "returnId": null,
                "user": {
                    "name": "Leaon H.",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Admin"
                    }
                },
                "due": {
                    "title": "Purchased Product",
                    "description": null,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "amount": "264514.32",
                    "remain": "4.32",
                    "fullPaidDate": null,
                    "collection": "264510.00",
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "paid": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    }
                },
                "customer": {
                    "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                    "phone": "123",
                    "address": "1"
                },
                "return": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Samung Monitor",
                "quantity": 2,
                "date": "2022-12-29",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                "status": "due",
                "percentage": "20.00",
                "less": "66128.58",
                "discountPrice": "512.72",
                "deposit": "264510.00",
                "change": "0.00",
                "subtotal": "640.90",
                "userId": 1,
                "orderId": 264,
                "customerId": 126,
                "dueId": 90,
                "returnId": null,
                "user": {
                    "name": "Leaon H.",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Admin"
                    }
                },
                "due": {
                    "title": "Purchased Product",
                    "description": null,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "amount": "264514.32",
                    "remain": "4.32",
                    "fullPaidDate": null,
                    "collection": "264510.00",
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "paid": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    }
                },
                "customer": {
                    "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                    "phone": "123",
                    "address": "1"
                },
                "return": null
            },
            {
                "name": "LG Monitor",
                "quantity": 1,
                "date": "2022-12-29",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                "status": "due",
                "percentage": "20.00",
                "less": "66128.58",
                "discountPrice": "0.80",
                "deposit": "264510.00",
                "change": "0.00",
                "subtotal": "1.00",
                "userId": 1,
                "orderId": 264,
                "customerId": 126,
                "dueId": 90,
                "returnId": null,
                "user": {
                    "name": "Leaon H.",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Admin"
                    }
                },
                "due": {
                    "title": "Purchased Product",
                    "description": null,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "amount": "264514.32",
                    "remain": "4.32",
                    "fullPaidDate": null,
                    "collection": "264510.00",
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "paid": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    }
                },
                "customer": {
                    "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                    "phone": "123",
                    "address": "1"
                },
                "return": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Samsung HDD ",
                "quantity": 1,
                "date": "2022-12-29",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                "status": "due",
                "percentage": "20.00",
                "less": "66128.58",
                "discountPrice": "0.80",
                "deposit": "264510.00",
                "change": "0.00",
                "subtotal": "1.00",
                "userId": 1,
                "orderId": 264,
                "customerId": 126,
                "dueId": 90,
                "returnId": null,
                "user": {
                    "name": "Leaon H.",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Admin"
                    }
                },
                "due": {
                    "title": "Purchased Product",
                    "description": null,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "amount": "264514.32",
                    "remain": "4.32",
                    "fullPaidDate": null,
                    "collection": "264510.00",
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "paid": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    }
                },
                "customer": {
                    "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                    "phone": "123",
                    "address": "1"
                },
                "return": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 265,
        "orderId": "PVDZGSQIO",
        "date": "2022-12-29",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:43:27.000Z",
        "sale": [
            {
                "name": "Keyboard",
                "quantity": 1,
                "date": "2022-12-29",
                "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:43:27.000Z",
                "status": "paid",
                "percentage": "20.00",
                "less": "22000.00",
                "discountPrice": "88000.00",
                "deposit": "110000.00",
                "change": "22000.00",
                "subtotal": "110000.00",
                "userId": 1,
                "orderId": 265,
                "customerId": 133,
                "dueId": null,
                "returnId": null,
                "user": {
                    "name": "Leaon H.",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Admin"
                    }
                },
                "due": null,
                "customer": {
                    "name": "Badhon",
                    "phone": "01733110243",
                    "address": "Jessore"
                },
                "return": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 267,
        "orderId": "-7LDATFVL",
        "date": "2023-01-02",
        "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
        "sale": [
            {
                "name": "Keyboard",
                "quantity": 1,
                "date": "2023-01-02",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
                "status": "due",
                "percentage": "0.00",
                "less": "0.00",
                "discountPrice": "20050.90",
                "deposit": "0.00",
                "change": "0.00",
                "subtotal": "20050.90",
                "userId": 1,
                "orderId": 267,
                "customerId": 126,
                "dueId": 92,
                "returnId": null,
                "user": {
                    "name": "Leaon H.",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Admin"
                    }
                },
                "due": {
                    "title": "Purchased Product",
                    "description": null,
                    "date": "2023-01-02",
                    "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
                    "amount": "20050.90",
                    "remain": "20050.90",
                    "fullPaidDate": null,
                    "collection": "0.00",
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "paid": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    }
                },
                "customer": {
                    "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                    "phone": "123",
                    "address": "1"
                },
                "return": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how to get all rows?

Comment: [i just want data like this by date filter](https://ibb.co/W34S5m7)

Comment: Please show all code pieces as formatted code blocks instead of links to screenshots

Comment: sure! @Anatoly give me 1 min

Comment: And we need to see what associations `Order` model has

Comment: check last output **But I want this type of output:** `Order` and others **associations** already done. @Anatoly

Comment: Ok, that's better! Now can you please try the query without `all: true`? How many records will you have? If a number of records will still be incorrect then please include the generated SQL from the query in the post

Comment: @Anatoly, I remove `all: true` and it's make error -

"message": "Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object."

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove the whole `include` option, of course. My bad!

Comment: solved that issue, I import `const { Op } = require("sequelize")` and changed it to: `[db.lte] > [Op.lte]` and it works. Thank you so much @Anatoly you are such a great person trying to help me. I'm very thankful for giving me your valuable time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is **db.lte** (operators are not working correctly)

```
const db = require("../../utils/database");
```

> in database file ***("../../utils/database")***

```
const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
```

**previously:**

```
where: {
    date: {
        [db.lte]: last,
    },
},
```

**output:**

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "order": [
        {
            "id": 268,
            "orderId": "PTBRZQHRA",
            "date": "2023-01-03",
            "createdAt": "2023-01-03T04:26:48.000Z",
            "sale": [
                {
                    "name": "Samsung HDD ",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "date": "2023-01-03",
                    "createdAt": "2023-01-03T04:26:48.000Z",
                    "status": "due",
                    "percentage": "0.00",
                    "less": "0.00",
                    "discountPrice": "1.00",
                    "deposit": "0.00",
                    "change": "0.00",
                    "subtotal": "1.00",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 268,
                    "customerId": 133,
                    "dueId": 93,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": {
                        "title": "Purchased Product",
                        "description": null,
                        "date": "2023-01-03",
                        "createdAt": "2023-01-03T04:26:48.000Z",
                        "amount": "1.00",
                        "remain": "1.00",
                        "fullPaidDate": null,
                        "collection": "0.00",
                        "customerId": 133,
                        "paid": null,
                        "customer": {
                            "name": "Badhon",
                            "phone": "01733110243",
                            "address": "Jessore"
                        }
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Badhon",
                        "phone": "01733110243",
                        "address": "Jessore"
                    },
                    "return": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Then I change here:**

1. import

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
```

2. changed it to: **[db.lte] > [Op.lte]**

```
where: {
    date: {
        [Op.lte]: last,
    },
},
```

**output:**

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "order": [
        {
            "id": 264,
            "orderId": "YFEP6EP41",
            "date": "2022-12-29",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
            "sale": [
                {
                    "name": "Keyboard",
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "status": "due",
                    "percentage": "20.00",
                    "less": "66128.58",
                    "discountPrice": "264000.00",
                    "deposit": "264510.00",
                    "change": "0.00",
                    "subtotal": "330000.00",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 264,
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "dueId": 90,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": {
                        "title": "Purchased Product",
                        "description": null,
                        "date": "2022-12-29",
                        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                        "amount": "264514.32",
                        "remain": "4.32",
                        "fullPaidDate": null,
                        "collection": "264510.00",
                        "customerId": 126,
                        "paid": null,
                        "customer": {
                            "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                            "phone": "123",
                            "address": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    },
                    "return": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Samung Monitor",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "status": "due",
                    "percentage": "20.00",
                    "less": "66128.58",
                    "discountPrice": "512.72",
                    "deposit": "264510.00",
                    "change": "0.00",
                    "subtotal": "640.90",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 264,
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "dueId": 90,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": {
                        "title": "Purchased Product",
                        "description": null,
                        "date": "2022-12-29",
                        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                        "amount": "264514.32",
                        "remain": "4.32",
                        "fullPaidDate": null,
                        "collection": "264510.00",
                        "customerId": 126,
                        "paid": null,
                        "customer": {
                            "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                            "phone": "123",
                            "address": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    },
                    "return": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "LG Monitor",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "status": "due",
                    "percentage": "20.00",
                    "less": "66128.58",
                    "discountPrice": "0.80",
                    "deposit": "264510.00",
                    "change": "0.00",
                    "subtotal": "1.00",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 264,
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "dueId": 90,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": {
                        "title": "Purchased Product",
                        "description": null,
                        "date": "2022-12-29",
                        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                        "amount": "264514.32",
                        "remain": "4.32",
                        "fullPaidDate": null,
                        "collection": "264510.00",
                        "customerId": 126,
                        "paid": null,
                        "customer": {
                            "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                            "phone": "123",
                            "address": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    },
                    "return": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Samsung HDD ",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                    "status": "due",
                    "percentage": "20.00",
                    "less": "66128.58",
                    "discountPrice": "0.80",
                    "deposit": "264510.00",
                    "change": "0.00",
                    "subtotal": "1.00",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 264,
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "dueId": 90,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": {
                        "title": "Purchased Product",
                        "description": null,
                        "date": "2022-12-29",
                        "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:12:12.000Z",
                        "amount": "264514.32",
                        "remain": "4.32",
                        "fullPaidDate": null,
                        "collection": "264510.00",
                        "customerId": 126,
                        "paid": null,
                        "customer": {
                            "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                            "phone": "123",
                            "address": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    },
                    "return": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 265,
            "orderId": "PVDZGSQIO",
            "date": "2022-12-29",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:43:27.000Z",
            "sale": [
                {
                    "name": "Keyboard",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "date": "2022-12-29",
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-29T07:43:27.000Z",
                    "status": "paid",
                    "percentage": "20.00",
                    "less": "22000.00",
                    "discountPrice": "88000.00",
                    "deposit": "110000.00",
                    "change": "22000.00",
                    "subtotal": "110000.00",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 265,
                    "customerId": 133,
                    "dueId": null,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Badhon",
                        "phone": "01733110243",
                        "address": "Jessore"
                    },
                    "return": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 267,
            "orderId": "-7LDATFVL",
            "date": "2023-01-02",
            "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
            "sale": [
                {
                    "name": "Keyboard",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "date": "2023-01-02",
                    "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
                    "status": "due",
                    "percentage": "0.00",
                    "less": "0.00",
                    "discountPrice": "20050.90",
                    "deposit": "0.00",
                    "change": "0.00",
                    "subtotal": "20050.90",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 267,
                    "customerId": 126,
                    "dueId": 92,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": {
                        "title": "Purchased Product",
                        "description": null,
                        "date": "2023-01-02",
                        "createdAt": "2023-01-02T08:31:24.000Z",
                        "amount": "20050.90",
                        "remain": "20050.90",
                        "fullPaidDate": null,
                        "collection": "0.00",
                        "customerId": 126,
                        "paid": null,
                        "customer": {
                            "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                            "phone": "123",
                            "address": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Alvi Hasan",
                        "phone": "123",
                        "address": "1"
                    },
                    "return": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 268,
            "orderId": "PTBRZQHRA",
            "date": "2023-01-03",
            "createdAt": "2023-01-03T04:26:48.000Z",
            "sale": [
                {
                    "name": "Samsung HDD ",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "date": "2023-01-03",
                    "createdAt": "2023-01-03T04:26:48.000Z",
                    "status": "due",
                    "percentage": "0.00",
                    "less": "0.00",
                    "discountPrice": "1.00",
                    "deposit": "0.00",
                    "change": "0.00",
                    "subtotal": "1.00",
                    "userId": 1,
                    "orderId": 268,
                    "customerId": 133,
                    "dueId": 93,
                    "returnId": null,
                    "user": {
                        "name": "Leaon H.",
                        "role": {
                            "name": "Admin"
                        }
                    },
                    "due": {
                        "title": "Purchased Product",
                        "description": null,
                        "date": "2023-01-03",
                        "createdAt": "2023-01-03T04:26:48.000Z",
                        "amount": "1.00",
                        "remain": "1.00",
                        "fullPaidDate": null,
                        "collection": "0.00",
                        "customerId": 133,
                        "paid": null,
                        "customer": {
                            "name": "Badhon",
                            "phone": "01733110243",
                            "address": "Jessore"
                        }
                    },
                    "customer": {
                        "name": "Badhon",
                        "phone": "01733110243",
                        "address": "Jessore"
                    },
                    "return": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```